# Write PairDStram to cassandra using Datastax Spark Cassandra Connector

Tags: java, cassandra, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I need to write data of my filtered stream to cassandra using Java and Datastax Spark Cassandra Connector.

I followed the [datastax java documentation](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md).

The documentation explains how to write a RDD to cassandra, but not how to write a Dstream.

I need to be able to save a PairDStream and I don't know how to do it, because all examples are written in scala.

I need to turn the following code written in scala in the java's code:

```
val wc = stream.flatMap(_.split("\\s+"))
    .map(x => (x, 1))
    .reduceByKey(_ + _)
    .saveToCassandra("streaming_test", "words", SomeColumns("word", "count"))
```

Basically I have to save a `JavaPairDStream<String, Integer>`

Comment: Are you using Java 8? [It has streams.](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/#pipelines)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution, in case anyone looking for the answer

To write a DStream or JavaDStream to Cassandra, need to import:

```
import static com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraStreamingJavaUtil.*;
```

and use  `javaFunctions(DStream<T> arg0)` or `javaFunctions(JavaDStream<T> arg0)`